# In LTspice, is there a way to model a lossless tline in which physical length is passed as a parameter instead of Time Delay?

Tags: ltspice

By default, the input parameters are Zo and Td. However, I want to simulate the circuit and find out the simulated time delay, and provide the length of the line.

Comment: You first need to know either the dielectric constant or per-unit-length capacitance of the transmission line you want to simulate before the length means anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can't enter the length directly, but there is a way using the .param card.

See example below. 
The .param card defines length and calculates a number for the delay: \$  delay = {length \over {c \cdot velocity\_factor}} \$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ltline` (lossless `tline`) with `L=<...> C=<...> len=<...>`. The delay will be `sqrt(L*C)`. The default length is `1 m` (IIRC). By not providing `R=<...>` (resistive loss) the transmission line acts as ideal. There are several other options to go with these, don't forget that it needs a `.model` card (and check the help for those extra parameters).

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to simulate the circuit and find out the simulated time delay,
> and provide the length of the line*.

It looks like LTspice doesn't allow you to do this.

Microcap simulation software allows you to do this. Here I've used microcap to set the line length to 25 metres so I can see the signal delay with a high impedance on the end of the t-line: -

[image]

Inductance and capacitance of he t-line are set to 250 nH and100 pF (per metre). This produces a 50 ohm line as per the formula \$\sqrt{L/C}\$.

Comment: OP asked how to do this in LTSpice. You state very clearly that it can be done, but don't show how. I don't see any indication in the LTSpice manual that it can be done...so how do you do it?

Comment: @ThePhoton it appears it can't be done. Thank you; I shall amend my answer.

Comment: It actually can be done. There’s another transmission line element in LTspice called `ltline` (lossy transmission line) which matches the one you use in Microcap.

Comment: @SteKulov it was `ThePhoton` who told me it couldn't be done and I was surprised by this revelation (given also that I'd checked the internet for confirmation).

Comment: Right. I forgot to tag him. My bad. @ThePhoton